# Application error - When uploading my app on Heroku

Tags: heroku

Uploading my Django app on Heroku

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail

heroku logs:

```
2021-10-19T10:46:06.255667+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carpriceread.herokuapp.com request_id=704fd2ae-c1b2-4a0c-b359-dc215038a6f6 fwd="49.36.183.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-19T10:55:56.839196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carpriceread.herokuapp.com request_id=837a3401-418a-4063-91ec-2a97c89ada73 fwd="49.36.183.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-19T10:55:57.205478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carpriceread.herokuapp.com request_id=63d1e63e-f0aa-4f54-9989-7c7a423bc21d fwd="49.36.183.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-19T12:43:41.062044+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-19T12:43:43.722991+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-10-19T12:43:44.543820+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2021-10-19T12:43:44.669170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-10-19T12:43:44.788929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-10-19T16:27:49.633265+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carpriceread.herokuapp.com request_id=6ef8172a-9ac4-403d-b2ee-4111dfd9767a fwd="49.36.183.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-19T16:27:50.150801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carpriceread.herokuapp.com request_id=dbd50e93-7749-47a4-a78d-3aa74b8a450a fwd="49.36.183.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

repo link:
https://github.com/tan404/Predict-Car-Selling-Price

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtul environment in your app then you have to pip install gunicorn and create a procfile and then you have to write a single line in that procfile so that heroku can detect it, see the below video for help.
https://youtu.be/Li0Abz-KT78